# PHP - Created a zip file from a single file

Tags: php, laravel, zip

have everything working including all the password protection parts but can't get past this last issue.

The requirement is on a Laravel app, a CSV is created and downloaded as a password protected zip.

To do this I have a class that stores the CSV locally, then a method that calls the following:

```
echo system('zip -P ' .$this->password. ' ' .$this->getZipStoragePath(). ' ' .storage_path('app/').$this->getFilePath());
```

This 'works' in that it creates a password protected zip file. But when extracted, there is a folder structure of my machine up to the point to point to find this file.

So, extracting this created zip gives me a directory of:

```
Users > Craig > Apps > Project Name > Storage > app > temp > then the file here.
```

Is there a way I can use the same zip system method but have it only zip up the file and not the whole path as returned with the storage_path() method?

Comment: Have you tried using PHP's ZipArchive?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want the `-j` flag:

```
-j
--junk-paths
     Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do
     not store directory names. By default, zip will store the
     full path (relative to the current directory).
```

Also note that you can use the native PHP Zip support, and call [`addFile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) with the optional second argument to override the filename inside the archive.

Comment: ...and you can set a password with `setPassword()`

Comment: Quick response, and the flag works! Thanks. However, the ZipArchive doesn't allow actual password setting from my research? http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php#116848